# facebook C# SDK , graph API V1.0 deprecated effects

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been using Facebook C# SDK (6.0.10.0) in an app. I use the C# sdk to do all facebook operations authentication/friend list/friend details...!
As Graph API v1.0 is deprecated by facebook, will the use of C# SDK has any effects ? Do I need to update/upgrade anything in using the facebook C# SDK ? 
Any lead to the information will be useful.